# Spring Security OAuth2 - How to modify token response JSON?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am getting the Response JSON (for JWT token request) as below:

```
{
    "access_token": "<JWT Access Token>",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "<JWT Refresh Token>",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read write trust",
    "DateOfBirth": "01-01-1990",
    "Address_Line_1": "ABCD Andrews Dr, Apt 111",
    "PAN_Number": "12345ABCD",
    "Address_Line_2": "Dublin, CA 94588",
    "jti": "e6a19730-e4e5-4cec-bf59-bd90ca1acc34"
}
```

I want to modify it (by removing a few elements) to:

```
{
    "access_token": "<JWT Access Token>",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "<JWT Refresh Token>",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read write trust",
    "jti": "e6a19730-e4e5-4cec-bf59-bd90ca1acc34"
}
```

I tried to used ResponseBodyAdvice as adviced by a few. But issue is response body object (available as public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object **body** ...) is of object type - "org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken" and not JSON. I am not sure how i can manipulate DefaultOAuth2AccessToken to remove the additional elements.

Could anybody please help me?

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode(CLIENT_SECRET))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken, OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("DateOfBirth", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("dob"));
        additionalInfo.put("PAN_Number", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("pan"));
        additionalInfo.put("Address_Line_1", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("addr1"));
        additionalInfo.put("Address_Line_2", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("addr2"));
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) oAuth2AccessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return oAuth2AccessToken;
    }
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseJSONAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends
    HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        /*
          Logic to remove additional elements from response JSON.
          But Object body is of type org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken and not JSON!!
        */
        return body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you have to adjust your token enhance that you configure in your `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`
in the method

```java
public void configure(
  AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
      Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
     
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
             .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
             .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

you can set your custom enhance or configure one. This should allow you to turn on or off what is send with the token

Comment: Hi jojo_Berlin,  I am already using TokenEnhancer to add custom claims in the token.  Just added my code in the question. Thanks

Comment: yeah if you remove `additionalInfo.put("DateOfBirth", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("dob"));
        additionalInfo.put("PAN_Number", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("pan"));
        additionalInfo.put("Address_Line_1", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("addr1"));
        additionalInfo.put("Address_Line_2", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("addr2"));` this will solve your problem

Comment: Hi jojo_Berlin, I need PAN_Number/Address_Line_1/Address_Line_2 inside the JWT Access Token as Custom Claims. Issue is TokenEnhancer does that, but also add them inside the Token response JSON.

Comment: Here is the generated JWT Token payload: ```{
  "DateOfBirth": "01-01-1990",
  "Address_Line_1": "ABCD Andrews Dr, Apt 111",
  "user_name": "john",
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write",
    "trust"
  ],
  "PAN_Number": "12345ABCD",
  "Address_Line_2": "Dublin, CA 94588",
  "exp": 1548929641,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_USER"
  ],
  "jti": "2d8c8bee-20e4-4efd-a131-3096d238d166",
  "client_id": "abcdefghij"
}```

Comment: I don't get your point why do you need to put it inside the claim, if you don't want to have it in the JWT?

Comment: Response from spring security server /oauth/token endpoint: 
```{
    "access_token": "<JWT Access Token>",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "<JWT Refresh Token>",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read write trust",
    "DateOfBirth": "01-01-1990",
    "Address_Line_1": "ABCD Andrews Dr, Apt 111",
    "PAN_Number": "12345ABCD",
    "Address_Line_2": "Dublin, CA 94588",
    "jti": "e6a19730-e4e5-4cec-bf59-bd90ca1acc34"
}```

Comment: "<JWT Access Token>" above has the payload ```{ "DateOfBirth": "01-01-1990", "Address_Line_1": "ABCD Andrews Dr, Apt 111", "user_name": "john", "scope": [ "read", "write", "trust" ], "PAN_Number": "12345ABCD", "Address_Line_2": "Dublin, CA 94588", "exp": 1548929641, "authorities": [ "ROLE_USER" ], "jti": "2d8c8bee-20e4-4efd-a131-3096d238d166", "client_id": "abcdefghij" }``` Note DateOfBirth/Address_Line_1/PAN_Number/Address_Line_2 are coming in both...

Answer (score 0):

Keep using ResponseBodyAdvice, first define a class which have all field you want to show. Then make method beforeBodyWrite return that class. In beforeBodyWrite method you want to set field of defined class by value of body, then return it.

Sorry i don't good at english, ask me if u don't get it ;)

```java
public BaseResponse beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends     HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        BaseResponse res = new BaseResponse();
        res.setResponseStatusCode(StatusResponse.SUCCESS.getCode()); 
        res.setResponseStatusMessage(StatusResponse.SUCCESS.getName()); 
        res.setContent(body);
        return res;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some sample code to your answer? Don't just describe code - write it. :)

Comment: `public BaseResponse beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends
 HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
     BaseResponse res = new BaseResponse();
     res.setResponseStatusCode(StatusResponse.SUCCESS.getCode());
     res.setResponseStatusMessage(StatusResponse.SUCCESS.getName());
     res.setContent(body);
     return res;
    }
 }`

Comment: the result : `{
"responseStatusCode": 2000,
"responseStatusMessage": "SUCCESS",
"content": {
"access_token": "566c5b52-5947-4902-ac04-43b44e1ea8b3",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "cade417d-1838-4d6d-b4b1-bc0c9b4519b6",
"expires_in": 84115,
"scope": "read write delete"
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter(), tokenEnhancer()));

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
```